# Bootstrap/Angular dropdown not working in IE11

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

This is a simple drop down, but in IE11 you cannot see the chosen menu item. Do you know any workarounds?

```
<div class="form-group program-container">
  <select class="form-control  container-fluid" (change)="onChooseMenuItem($event)" [(ngModel)]="ngrxActiveMenuItem">
    <option class="selected-class" selected disabled>{{ngrxActiveMenuItem}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let menuItem of ngrxMenuItems, let i = index"
            value={{i}}>
      {{menuItem.programName}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

this is the top component:

```
<div class="container home-container">
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="card border-left-primary shadow-sm py-2 h-100">
        <div class="card-body pt-2 pb-2">
          <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">
              Programs:
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 mt-3">
              <app-program-dropdown></app-program-dropdown>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: any error in the browser console ?

Comment: nope, console clean as new

Comment: you can post the code of the component, which has the dropdown integrated ?

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether your code works in the other browsers? does this issue only occur in the IE 11 browser? You can try to show the sample code via stackblitz example so that we can try to see its result. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding [selected] instead of what you have:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let menuItem of ngrxMenuItems, let i = index"
        value={{I}} [selected]="menuItem.programName == ngrxActiveMenuItem">
  {{menuItem.programName}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There would be a file browserslist in your project folder. You may try adding IE11 in it.